# 2 filters on dataframe in R subset

Tags: r

I wouldn't be posting this if it wasn't driving me insane.

What am I missing here?  It filters by the first criteria but not the second.  If I replace the first criteria (dclDowntimeCD with the pdn_process, it works.  But using | to use both of them at the same time does not.

```
tc2 <- tc[nchar(tc$dclDowntimeCd) < 1 | tc$pdn_process == 'Casting',]


row    dclDowntimeCd    pdn_process alloy
1      452              Casting     3003
2                       Casting     3003
3                       Smoothing   3003
4      23               Smoothing   3003
```

Here the desired result would be row 2 only

Has something changed with the | operator to combine multiple filters?

Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing the contents of `tc`.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the contents, I just think there's a problem with how I'm wanting to use both filters.  If I use them individually, they work which is baffling me - ha!

Comment: Yes but if you want people to answer, they need data to work with.

Comment: Sorry about that, added an example.

Comment: Could you paste the result of `dput(tc)` ? It's difficult to know how the missing values for `dclDowntimeCd` in your example are represented.

Comment: In addition: if the desired result is row 2, your filter should be 'and' (`&`) not "or" (`|`), and `nchar(x) < 0` is probably not a good test for missing values.

Comment: Ah, yes. There we have it.  Thank you sir.  I guess I misinterpreted how my how the vectors were structured and my filter.